# Javascript image rollover - need captions, how do I add them?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using javascript to make a sort of vacation slideshow, where the main image changes depending on what link you're hovering over. I'm still new to javascript, and have spent the last two hours trying to figure out how to get the image to now display a caption underneath, I'd really love some help.

This is my js file:

```
var canadaOver = new Image();
canadaOver.src = 'images/canada.jpg';
var italyOver = new Image();
italyOver.src = 'images/italy.jpg';
var ukraineOver = new Image();
ukraineOver.src = 'images/ukraine.jpg';
var japanOver = new Image();
japanOver.src = 'images/japan.jpg';
var icelandOver = new Image();
icelandOver.src = 'images/iceland.jpg';
document.getElementById("canada").onmouseover = doMouseOver;
document.getElementById("italy").onmouseover = doMouseOver;
document.getElementById("ukraine").onmouseover = doMouseOver;
document.getElementById("japan").onmouseover = doMouseOver;
document.getElementById("iceland").onmouseover = doMouseOver;


function doMouseOver(evt)  {
var anchor = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
var img = document.getElementById("destinations");
var textDiv = document.getElementById('caption');
if (anchor.id == "canada")    {
        img.src = canadaOver.src;
    }
    else if (anchor.id == "italy")
    {
        img.src = italyOver.src;
        textDiv.innerHTML = imgText;
    }
    else if (anchor.id == "ukraine")    {
        img.src = ukraineOver.src;
        textDiv.innerHTML = imgText;
        }
    else if (anchor.id == "japan")    {
        img.src = japanOver.src;
        textDiv.innerHTML = imgText;
        }
    else if (anchor.id == "iceland")    {
        img.src = icelandOver.src;
        textDiv.innerHTML = imgText;
        }
        }
```

My links are in a table next to the main image. I just can't figure out where the captions even go!

Comment: Post your html markup as well

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for

https://jsfiddle.net/84cfy1Lf/

HTML

```
<body>
  <section id="country-stuff">

  </section>
</body>
```

SCRIPT

```
var countries = ['canada', 'italy', 'ukraine', 'japan', 'iceland'];

countries.forEach(function(country) {
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.id = country;
  img.className = 'image';
  img.src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/06/CallingCodesWorld-Labeled.svg/500px-CallingCodesWorld-Labeled.svg.png' // swap for real image director:  images/' + country +'.jpg';

  var mouser = document.getElementById('country-stuff').appendChild(img);

  mouser.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
    doMouseOver(event);
  })
});

var caption = document.createElement('div');
caption.id = 'caption';
document.getElementById('country-stuff').appendChild(caption);


function doMouseOver(event) {
  var anchor = event.target;
  populateCountryText(anchor)
}


function populateCountryText(anchor) {
  document.getElementById('caption').innerHTML = event.target.id;

  return caption;
}
```

CSS

```
.image {
  width: 150px;
}
```